# Where should I define the "drupal_stale_file_threshold" Drupal variable?

Tags: configuration

I want to delete my CSS and JavaScript files every day. Where do I define the "drupal_stale_file_threshold" variable?

- In the template.php file with `variable_set('drupal_stale_file_threshold', 86400);`
- In the settings.php file with `$conf['drupal_stale_file_threshold'] = 86400;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings.php makes sense if the setting isn't supposed to change.

A module may be useful if the value of the setting is just temporary.

A themes template.php file is absolute **not** the place to put it.